# Difference between power and falling power

Tags: combinatorics

I have the following question about the difference between a falling power equation and a very similar equation using normal power:
Let $m$ and $C$ be some positive integer constants, where $C > m$, and let:

$f(x) = \frac{(C-x)^\underline{m}}{D^\underline{m}}$

where $\underline{m}$ above denotes the falling factorial (e.g.: $x^\underline{4} = x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$).

$g(x) = \frac{(C-x)^m}{D^m}$, where $0\leq x \leq C$.

The reason for this is that $g(x)$ seems to be a "reasonable'' (for my purposes) approximation of $f(x)$. But I would like to know how "inaccurate" $g(x)$ is from $f(x)$.

To this end, I would like to know about the difference $d(x) = f(x) - g(x)$ and in particular how big it can get over the valid values of $x$. I have made a few plots and found that $d(x)$ will always have a single hump (largest difference) for some value of $x$. An example is like below ($C = 128$, $m=4$, y-axis is $d(x)$, x-axis is $x$):

[image: values of $d(x)$ with $C = 128$, $m=4$]

Also, as $C$ increases in size, I find that the largest value of $d(x)$ gets smaller and smaller.

How can I prove this observation or maybe even show some bounds on it? Could someone give me some pointers or direction on how to approach answering the above question?

Thank you so much!

Comment: What is the difference between $\underline{m}$ and $m$?

Comment: Ah, my bad, I was using $x^\underline{m}$ to denote the falling factorial: $x^\underline{m} = x(x-1)(x-2)...(x-m+1)$. I will edit my post to make this clearer.